# Adding another worksheet in the excel

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a code which will fetch information from 2 servers and store in 2 different dictionaries. I wanted to write both the data into 2 worksheets into an excel. Unfortunately i am not able to see the first sheet. The second sheet always overrides the first sheet. Please see the code which i wrote below.

**Note**: Due to security reasons, i didn't put the actual code but a similar code in the block.

```
import xlwt

def dicttest1():
    d1 = {}
    string = 'UK_PDL_HE'
    j=0
    for i in range (1,10):
        d1[i] = j
        j+=1
    write_data(d1,string,1)

def dicttest2():
    d2 = {}
    string = 'UK_DTH_HE'
    j=100
    for i in range (1,10):
        d2[i] = j
    write_data(d2,string,2)

def write_data(dictionary,string,sheetdata):
    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
    sheet = "sheet" + str(sheetdata)
    print sheet
    sheet = book.add_sheet(string)
    sheet.write(0, 0, "#")
    sheet.write(0, 1, "Component")
    sheet.write(0,2,'Version')
    i=0
    for key in dictionary:
        print key, dictionary[key]
        sheet.write(i+1, 0, i+1)
        sheet.write(i+1, 1, key)
        sheet.write(i+1, 2, dictionary[key])
        i+=1
    book.save("test_Version.xls")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dicttest1()
    dicttest2()
```

If i print the data separately on the console, i can see data are correct. The only problem is why is it overwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the first worksheet because every time you call `write_data`, you are instantiating a new `Workbook` object and then saving the changes at the end. Create the `Workbook` object outside of that function by moving the following line after your imports:

```
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
```